# contour.h_next() Error:tuple' object has no attribute 'h_next'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am trying to get plot the fitellipse on an image but contour iterator is throwing error.
not sure what is wrong as i am new to opencv.

this is the main code:

```
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
height, width, depth = img.shape
img01 = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
img1gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(img1gray,(5,5),0)
img1canny=cv2.Canny(img1blur,125, 300, apertureSize=5)
img1bin=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img1canny,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,13,2)
contours=cv2.findContours(img1bin,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in contour_iterator(contours):
if len(i)>=6:
    PointArray2D32f = cv.CreateMat(1,len(i),cv.CV_32F)
    for (j, (x, y)) in enumerate(i):
        PointArray2D32f[0, j] = (x, y)
    gray = cv.CV_RGB(100, 100, 100)
    cv.DrawContours(img01, i, gray, gray,0,1,8,(0,0))
(center, size, angle)=cv2.fitEllipse(contours)
center = (cv.Round(center[0]), cv.Round(center[1]))
size = (cv.Round(size[0] * 0.5), cv.Round(size[1] * 0.5))
color = cv.CV_RGB(random.randrange(256),random.randrange(256),random.randrange(256))
cv.Ellipse(img01, center, size,angle, 0, 360,color, 2, cv.CV_AA, 0)
cv2.imshow("result",img01)
```

this is the contour iterator:(error in this function)

```
def contour_iterator(contour):
while contour:
    yield contour
    contour = contour.h_next()//line of error
```

the iterator code was taken from sample codes in scource
the errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dell\workspace\imgrec\imgpros.py", line 33, in <module>
for i in contour_iterator(contours):
File "C:\Users\dell\workspace\imgrec\imgpros.py", line 16, in contour_iterator
contour = contour.h_next()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'h_next'
```

thank you

Comment: oh, please don't use the old cv api, stick with cv2 !

Comment: you got a contour from cv2. you can't process it with cv methods

Comment: so is that causes the problem ?

Comment: so what is the cv2 version of the method and could you provide me with a link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the cv2 API. Mixing old and new is the straight road to disaster.

Here you go:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img1bin,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours( img, contours,-1, (128,255,255), 2)
for cnt in contours:
    if len(cnt) > 5: # at least 5 pts needed
        box = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
        cv2.ellipse(img,box,(0,0,200), 2)
cv2.imshow('contours', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.fitEllipse

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/python2